# Most efficient way of nested order, group, sum of count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

User has_many :products
Products has_many :likes

I want to return records in descending order for users based on the total number of likes they got.

e.g. 
User 1 has products (A, B, C)
A = 4 likes, B = 2 likes, C = 1 like, Total = 7 likes

User 2 has products (D, E)
D = 4 likes, E = 6 likes, Total = 10 likes

User 3 has products (F, G, H, I)
F, G, H, I = each 1 like, Total = 4 likes

Result => User 2, User 1, User 3

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to make use of counter cache here to track the number of like for each product. For that we need to add a new column likes_count of type integer to products table.

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products
 scope :popular_products, joins(:products).group("user_id").
        order("sum(likes_count) DESC")
end
```

Product Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes
end
```

Like Model:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product , :counter_cache => true
end
```